# How can I send AJAX request for the content which are loaded via Infinite Scroll?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm building a simple project something like Twitter but very simple :)  There are a lot of tweets on user's homepage (timeline). So every tweet has *favorite* button. When user clicks to favorite button, it sends AJAX request to the server to store favorited tweet. So favorite buttons are somethings like this:

```
<a href="#" id="1"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="2"><i class="icon-star"></i></a>
<a href="#" id="3"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
...
...
```

I use the following JavaScript to send AJAX request:

```
$("i").on("click", function() {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("icon-star-empty") ){
        ajaxURL = "/setFavorite"
    } else{
        ajaxURL = "/removeFavorite"
    }

    var linkID = $(this).parent().prop("id");
    var obj    = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: {quoteID : linkID},
        success: function() {
            obj.hasClass("icon-star") ? obj.removeClass("icon-star").addClass("icon-star-empty") : obj.removeClass("icon-star-empty").addClass("icon-star");
        }
    });
})
```

Since there are a lot of tweets, I set [Infinite Scroll Plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). AJAX requests work well when I didn't set Infinite Scroll. But when I set, those  AJAX requests don't work for those tweets which are loaded via Infinite Scroll. I mean, when I click to the favorite button of the tweets which are loaded via Infinite Scroll, they don't send AJAX request to the server. But AJAX requests work with the tweets which are loaded via  default HTML not Infinite Scroll.

So my question is how can I solve this problem? How can I send AJAX request for the tweets which are loaded via Infinite Scroll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not related, HTML IDs shouldn't start with a number

Comment: I used number IDs, it works well when I don't set Infinite Scroll. So I think problem is not depend on that.

Comment: I said "not related", just letting you know that they may work, but aren't valid HTML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're valid in HTML5 but not a good practice anyway

Comment: Numeric IDs are valid in the HTML5 spec. (+1 @elclanrs)

Comment: OK, I got it ) I changed IDs, but it doesn't work either :( What can I do? Please help (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('selector').on('event', callback)` only binds events for the elements that exist at the time where the selector is processed. However, the infinite-scrolling code loads new elements later so no event is bound for them.

The solution is using a delegate:

```
$('selector').on('click', 'i', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

`selector` needs to be a parent element that contains all your (dynamically added) `i` elements.